# Showing that any norm is Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am asked to prove that in a normed space the norm is Lipschitz. I have seen concrete examples but never something general. If one has a norm $||x||$, the distance is induced by $d(x,y) = ||x-y||$. Therefore, the condition to satisfy would be finding a certain constant $K$ such that $|||x|-||y|| \leq ||x-y||$. I think that using the inverse triangle inequality would be the direct proof, using $K = 1$ as a Lipschitz constant. However, it seems weird to me that it is so easy. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are missing nothing.

Comment: Then I suppose that I can conclude with that and it is over, right?

Comment: Only thing I’d comment on is that in your proof, instead of saying “inverse triangle inequality”, maybe just write the regular triangle inequality $\|x\|\leq \|x-y\| + \|y\|$ and subtract from both sides (and do it with $x$ and $y$ swapped as well to show you can put absolute value on left hand side).  This is just because I don’t know if “inverse triangle inequality” is a standard term (I don’t use it), so maybe just do the proof of that. At most levels you just say “by the triangle inequality” and trust reader to do the math but in beginning courses you might just write it out.